# Tabulator - How to refresh table from json file

Tags: tabulator

I am trying to update my Tabulator table from a JSON file.  When an item is submitted or deleted, it triggers a PHP file that updates the file fine.  However, the table does not update.  If I hard reload the page (CTRL+F5), the table updates correctly.  Otherwise, it will not update with a regular reload.  I have a `location.refresh();` in my code for deleting with a successful ajax request to my PHP file.  My PHP files have a `"Refresh:0; url = tabulator.html"`.  I have tried adding to the top of my html page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

and to the top of my PHP file:

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'); // HTTP 1.1.
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
header('Pragma: no-cache'); // HTTP 1.0.
header('Expires: 0');
```

At the end of my table creation i have `table.setData();` since I use an ajaxURL to load the data in the table.  Anyone have any idea how I can refresh the table with the data from the JSON file when an item is submitted or deleted?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use     `reactiveData:true, //enable reactive data`
checkc [documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/release#reactive-data)

Comment: Thank you.  It seems to work when I use wampserver and locally host all the files.  However, when it is actually up on my website, it doesn't seem to make any difference.  Using bluehost if that matters.

Comment: It might have to do with the website and some settings in it.  I will have to look through my plugins and the site setup.  This should be the answer though since it works on the wampserver.  Thanks again.